# My li value dissappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to develope a e-learning site for kids. It contains an excercise to select the right answer among the given four options,by seeing the clue image. When the kid selects the right answer,the answer changes to green with right.png image,while selecting the wrong answer it changes to red with wrong.png image. the problem here is while clicking on either right.png or wrong.png the corresponding list (i.e) li value dissapears.can anybody help me to solve this.

My html code is-

```
<ul class="list gift">
    <li>gasp</li>
    <li>gift</li>
    <li>golf</li>
    <li>gust</li>
</ul>`
```

My Javascript-

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
    $('ul.gift li').click(function(e) 
    { 
        correct = "gift";
        needed = $(this).text();

        if(correct==needed){
            $( e.target ).closest("li").empty();
            $innercontent = '<li style="color: green;">'+ needed +'<img src="images/right.png"></li>';
            $( e.target ).closest("li").html($innercontent);

        }else{
            $( e.target ).closest("li").empty();
            $innercontent = '<li style="color: red;">'+ needed +'<img src="images/wrong.png"></li>';
            $( e.target ).closest("li").html($innercontent);
        }   

    });
});
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the `.click()` is executed the second time when you click the image.

You can fix this by using `.one()` instead of `.click()`. If you use `.one()` with the click handler, it is executed only once.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.gift li').one("click", function(e){ 
    var correct = "gift";
    var needed = $(this).text();

    if(correct==needed){
      $( e.target ).closest("li").empty();
      $innercontent = '<li style="color: green;">'+ needed +'<img src="images/right.png"></li>';
      $( e.target ).closest("li").html($innercontent);
    }
    else{
      $( e.target ).closest("li").empty();
      $innercontent = '<li style="color: red;">'+ needed +'<img src="images/wrong.png"></li>';
      $( e.target ).closest("li").html($innercontent);
    }   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list gift">
  <li>gasp</li>
  <li>gift</li>
  <li>golf</li>
  <li>gust</li>
</ul>
```

Learn more: [`.one()` | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Or use `.one()` to bind the handler in the first place.

Comment: Or hide the other answers and change the class

Comment: Exactly what i needed @Rahul Desai & Barmar..Thanks All